# Automatically add blank space inbetween characters

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrofields

How do I add blank spaces inbetween character? I'm using a PDF/AcroField;

[image]

See the routing field, I'd like to make "12345" into "1 2 3 4 5".

Javascript is allowed to validate forms, so maybe I can use that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to add blank spaces in between characters.

```
var string = "12345";
string.split('').join(' '); // String.split + Array.join
string.replace(/(.)/g, "$1 ").trim(); // Regex
```

You could also use a for-loop. etc.

As for your follow-up question about how to read AcroField values, based on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056401/how-do-i-get-all-the-fields-and-value-from-a-pdf-file-using-itext) I'd suggest trying something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader( pdfPath );
AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
Set<String> fldNames = fields.getFields().keySet();

for (String fldName : fldNames) {
  System.out.println( fldName + ": " + fields.getField( fldName ) );
}
```

Comment: How to I set the string to be equal to the value of the AcroField?

Comment: You asked how to add blank spaces in between characters in a string, so that's what I gave an example of. ;) I've never used AcroField before but based on what I see online..I'll update my example.