# get TEXTFIELD content(text) in pdf

Tags: java, itext

I have already tried many times in java.
I want to ask how to get TextField content(text) in a existing PDF.
The PDf is created by me using itext.
Thank you.

Comment: I used PdfReader to read a pdf existing some textfield with texts that I created .
But I have no idea how to extract those text in the text fields, I can only just extract all the text in the pdf.

Comment: Have you tried something like presented in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6062839/1729265)?