# PdfTextFormField values is not getting populated with iText 7.2.0

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

In my .Net project, I am using

```
    <PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="7.2.0" />
```

In c# class,

```
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

PdfTextFormField borrowerField = PdfFormField.CreateText(pdf);

borrowerField.SetFieldName("Borrowers_Name");
borrowerField.SetValue("Name");
form.AddField(borrowerField);
```

I can see field name as "Borrowers_Name" but value is iText.Forms.Fields.PdfTextFormField instead of Name.
Hence in my PDF, I see value as blank.

When I try to get value using

```
form.GetField("Borrowers_Name").GetValueAsString();
```

I can see value which is set. But when I open up the pdf, it's empty.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941615/is-itext7-available-in-vb-net-or-only-c-sharp/68946796#68946796 (it's in VB.NET, but should be easy to convert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a form field but you don't define its area on page. Thus, the field is created as invisible field.

The easiest way to define an on-page area for your field is in the creation method, e.g. by replacing

```
PdfTextFormField borrowerField = PdfFormField.CreateText(pdf);
```

by

```
PdfTextFormField borrowerField = PdfFormField.CreateText(pdf, new Rectangle(100, 600, 200, 20));
```

With this you get a visual representation of your field like this:

[image: Screen shot of field]

Comment: That solved the problem Thanks @mkl